# Mouthguards with bad teeth

Tags: equipment, maintenance

I'm 15 years old and require a new mouthguard for the Hockey season, the only problem is I haven't been able to find anything to help with my problematic tooth (don't know the medical term).
Just wondering if any "boil and bites" would work on this or if I'm going to have to pay more for a custom fit mouthguard! (And yes, I have went through orthodontic work but it was too much hassle so I stopped it before completion) [image: As you can see it's quite high up for a tooth and is not coming down!]

Comment: I notice that there are a couple of close votes on this question. I haven't voted to close it, but I do feel a little uneasy about it. This is because I'm worried that any answers *could* be constituted as medical advice which is [off-topic](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: This answer concerns techniques for modifying equipment to suit a circumstance which is irregular or for which most players and equipment manufacturers do not account. Answers that aim to give medical advice should be deleted, but the potential for them to be given does not mean all or most answers would do so. **VTLO**

Answer (score 1):

Having dealt with similarly out-of-alignment teeth when fitting a mouthguard, an excellent 'hack' is using scissors to remove part of the "wall" from a boil-and-bite mouth guard where the tooth would block it, then fit as normal.

However, the tooth will continue to pose a risk of injury through piercing the gum or cheek, or having less protection for the tooth itself. Discuss with your dentist or orthodontist how this can be addressed. It's a hassle to have emergency treatment for gashes in the mouth or fractured teeth, too.

Comment: Do you recommend cutting the whole wall out where the tooth is or just "thinning" the wall out?

Comment: @LewisMc I removed a notch from the wall, so that it had a cross-section like **L**.

Comment: @downvoye If you're going to do that to a reasonable suggestion based on direct experience, at least say what you think is the problem.